# DataGrid Group Header not Updating on new Record

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am having issues with the DataGrid Grouping Header updating. When I add or delete a record the total does not update unless i resort it and sometimes even editing the amount does not update the total.  I added INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject and IsLiveGroupingRequested per the suggestions of some of the forum posts that i read with no luck.  I put a breakpoint on the converter function and i noticed that it is not firing when i add/remove/edit a record it is not firing until i sort the table. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Converter1 x:Key="c1"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs1" Source="{Binding Path=Lines, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Type"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid Name="_dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="0"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource c1}}" Padding="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>

</Window>
```

codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();


            Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
            transaction.Lines.Add(new TransactionLine() { Account = "ACCOUNT1", Type = "ACCOUNT", Amount = -41.86 });
            transaction.Lines.Add(new TransactionLine() { Account = "BUDGET1", Type = "BUDGET", Amount = 41.86 });
            transaction.Lines.Add(new TransactionLine() { Account = "CATEGORY1", Type = "CATEGORY", Amount = 41.86 });
            this.DataContext = transaction;

        }

    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public Transaction()
        {
            this.Lines = new ObservableCollection<TransactionLine>();
        }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Payee { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<TransactionLine> Lines { get; set; }
    }
    public class TransactionLine : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
    {

        void IEditableObject.BeginEdit()
        {

        }
        void IEditableObject.CancelEdit()
        {

        }
        void IEditableObject.EndEdit()
        {

        }

        public TransactionLine() { }

        private string _account;
        private string _type;
        private double _amount;

        public string Account
        {
            get
            {
                return this._account;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Account"));
                this._account = value;
            }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this._type;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Type"));
                this._type = value;
            }
        }
        public double Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return this._amount;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Amount"));
                this._amount = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }

    public class Converter1 : IValueConverter
    {

        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Math.Round(((CollectionViewGroup)value).Items.Sum(l => ((TransactionLine)l).Amount), 2);
        }
        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the converter is only invoked when the databound property is set. And since you are binding to the `CollectionViewGroup` itself, the `Convert` method won't be called when you add a new item to the `ObservableCollection<TransactionLine>`.

Instead of just binding to the `CollectionViewGroup` itself, you could use a `MultiBinding` and an `IMultiValueConverter` implementation to also bind to the `Count` property of the source collection:

```
public class Converter1 : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Math.Round(((CollectionViewGroup)values[0]).Items.Sum(l => ((TransactionLine)l).Amount), 2);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="0"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Padding="0">
                <Label.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource c1}">
                        <Binding Path="."  />
                        <Binding Path="Items.Count" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: ItemCount works just fine I don’t need count I need total. I only mentioned count because it worked and was something I tried while debugging. I do however agree with you that problem is converter is only invoked when bound the question is why?

Comment: You're getting the total from your converter. The reason why I bind to count is just for the converter to get invoked. Why? Because that's how converters work. When else would they be called?

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the PropertyChanged event before you assign the new value to the backing field. Make sure that you're invoking it after you assign `value` to your field.

```c#
public string Account
{
    get
    {
        return this._account;
    }
    set
    {
        this._account = value;
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Account"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn i saw that and was kicking my self for missing that and was hopeful i had a solution.  Made the change and still no change to the behavior of the app

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time on this problem and the lighter way I found to update group informations (for example group header) is the following :

```
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            DataInfosGrid.Items.Refresh();
        });
```

You can change your DataGrid ItemsSource too, but I think it's heavier for your application !

See yaa ! ;-D

Olivier.